# Python collections of non-base type?

Tags: python, collections

I'm learning python, and I'm a bit confused about which the purpose of the different data structures like list, tuples, dictionaries, sets.

For example, let's say cars are defined by Brand,Model,Horsepower
I wish to have a collection of cars on which I could

- sort by Horsepower, or brand
- compare by model (to erase duplicates)
- iterate simply with a for statement
- remove elements by model

What would be the best way to achieve this?

- Do I need to create a class Car, and redefine some functions (like operators == and > in C), then store them in a list
- Or should I make them a dictionary, or redefine a dictionary myself ? and then have python sort them for me (I think this is possible with the operator module, correct me if I'm wrong)
- something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like most things, there's more than one possible approach.

#### Using a class

The neatest would probably be to make a `Car` class. You don't need to redefine operators - just have some properties and a constructor.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, brand, model, hp):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.hp = hp
```

Then, if you wanted to compare by model:

```
car1 = Car('foo', 'bar', 23)
car2 = Car('baz', 'bar', 34)

if car1.model == car2.model:
    # models are equal
```

If you had a list of `Car` objects, and wanted to sort them by horsepower:

```
car1 = Car('foo', 'bar', 23)
car2 = Car('baz', 'bar', 34)
car3 = Car('baz', 'bar', 14)
car_list = [car1, car2, car3]

car_list.sort(key=lambda c: c.hp)
```

#### Using a dict

Of course, since all you'd be doing with the class is storing a set of properties, you could also just use dicts instead - you just lose the rigidity (and gain some flexibility). To mimic the code above, but with dicts:

```
{'brand': 'foo', 'model': 'bar', 'hp': 23}
```

Then, if you wanted to compare by model:

```
car1 = {'brand': 'foo', 'model': 'bar', 'hp': 23}
car2 = {'brand': 'baz', 'model': 'bar', 'hp': 34}

if car1['model'] == car2['model']:
    # models are equal
```

If you had a list of `Car` objects, and wanted to sort them by horsepower:

```
car1 = {'brand': 'foo', 'model': 'bar', 'hp': 23}
car2 = {'brand': 'baz', 'model': 'bar', 'hp': 34}
car2 = {'brand': 'baz', 'model': 'bar', 'hp': 14}
car_list = [car1, car2, car3]

car_list.sort(key=lambda c: c['hp'])
```

Comment: Using Car class and list works, but not with all list function :
using your example :
>>> print car1 in car_list<br/>
True
>>> carSought=Car('foo','bar',23)
>>> carSought in car_list
False

Comment: Right, because `in` for objects uses `__hash__` (iirc) which by default is based off of the object's reference. You could define a custom `__hash__` if you wanted that would just base it off certain properties, such that any two instances with identical values for those properties would hash the same (and thus be count as `in` a list if any references to identical objects were).

Comment: Think I got this working, by also defining a custom `__eq__` method for the car class ! Hope this wont trigger some side effects.
Thanks for your help Amber !

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with a class Car and a dict(model:Car) store different cars.